# Interstial after game complete

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have this java, and I need that once the game is complete it appears the interstitial. The point is that I want the interstitial banner to appear when the toast Game complete appears. How can I do it?

```
    // Loading banner ads
    MobileAds.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
    initViewId(v);


public void onGameComplete() {
    if (mMahjongListener != null) {
        mMahjongListener.onGameComplete();
    }
    mCompleted = true;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), this.getString(R.string.game), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MahjongContract.Mahjong.COL_COMPLETE, true);
    cv.put(MahjongContract.Mahjong.COL_CURRENT, (String) null);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MahjongContract.Mahjong.CONTENT_URI, mPuzzleId), cv, null,
            null);

}

public void onGameIncompletable() {
    if (mMahjongListener != null) {
        mMahjongListener.onGameIncompletable();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), this.getString(R.string.solution), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    resetPuzzle();
}
```

Comment: the duration of `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` is around 2 second, so when you start toast there after start delayed handler to show interstitial ad. like `final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 2 second
  }
}, 2000);`

Comment: but it does not appear after the message. how can I do it?

Comment: have you tried `
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }` in handler run method?, and write the handler code inside bottom of method `onGameComplete `

Comment: do not. I'm very new and I do not know how to put it.

Comment: ok just comment the `mInterstitialAd.setAdListener` code and add `if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }` in `onGameComplete()` and try.

Comment: perfect perfect. Thank you very much friend. It works perfect

Comment: just one thing like I could do to get the game completed first and then the interstitial banner?

Comment: i have added the answer, if it works then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

ok just comment the `mInterstitialAd.setAdListener` code and replace the `onGameComplete()`, like below

```
public void onGameComplete() {
    if (mMahjongListener != null) {
        mMahjongListener.onGameComplete();
    }
    mCompleted = true;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), this.getString(R.string.game), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MahjongContract.Mahjong.COL_COMPLETE, true);
    cv.put(MahjongContract.Mahjong.COL_CURRENT, (String) null);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MahjongContract.Mahjong.CONTENT_URI, mPuzzleId), cv, null,
            null);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to don't put the Handler otherwise the admob policy will gone be violate.